# NS2 Linux Ubuntu 18.04 xgraph Segmentation Fault

Tags: linux, segmentation-fault

I am currently trying to run NS2 on Ubuntu 18.04. Using the ns-allinone-2.35 package recommended by the main website (isi.edu), I am having a segmentation fault error when trying to run xgraph12.2. NS-2 and nam run fine - however, even when xgraph is 'installed' I get:

```
sdean@ubuntu:~/ns2/ns-allinone-2.35$ xgraph 
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

I have gone through several tutorials on the web that are supposed to address this problem with no success. I HAVE set the PATH and LIBRARY variables correctly along with changing it to run gcc/g++ 4.8. I understand I am trying to run an old software package on a newer OS, but NS-3 did not do what we needed. I am open to using an older OS. However, I had errors with `build-essentials autoconf automake libxmu-dev` on Linux older systems.

As another hint, through trying a couple different remedies messing around, I get a lot of permission denied output. I try running as sudo but still no luck.

Thank you

Comment: Check the core dump, you will get the issue there.

Answer (score 1):

Install Xgraph : `sudo apt install Xgraph` → You get a stable version 12.1 .

Testing Xgraph : 
`$ cd ns-allinone-2.35/xgraph-12.2/examples/ && xgraph xgtest.xg` .. And please note that 'xgraph' requires a file to open the "Xgraph GUI". I.e. `$ xgraph` does nothing.

"Permission denied" is a common error : If ns-allinone-2.xx was unpacked with 'sudo', or with a Windows© tool. Correct is :

```
$ tar xvf ns-allinone-2.35_gcc5.tar.gz
```

ns-allinone-2.35_gcc5.tar.gz, link https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B7S255p3kFXNVVlxR0ZNRGVORjQ/view?usp=sharing → This is the 2014 update, for gcc/g++ versions 4.4 .. 5.3 .

ns2-INFO https://drive.google.com/file/d/1FCjn-9fkR7tKeqClUpHsleaEdnoKRZzq/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Knud - thank you for the input. However, running `sudo apt install Xgraph` yields `No package xgraph found`

Even running xgraph with a test still yields `Segmentation Fault (core dumped)`

I have installed without using `sudo` and still get the same results.

Comment: Knud - I have been able to rid the SegFault using the more updated NS2 tar file you provided. However, when I run the `./configure` and `make install` I get problems. Specifcally:
`source='xgraph.c' object='xgraph.o' libtool=no \
DEPDIR=.deps depmode=none /bin/bash ./depcomp \
gcc-4.8 -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I.        -g    -c xgraph.c
/bin/bash: ./depcomp: No such file or directory`

Then running `xgraph <testfile>` I get `Command 'xgraph' not found` 

Would this also be responsible for some the failures running the test/validation suite?

Comment: 300 ns2 patches https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/0B7S255p3kFXNZ2lWZDBRSW40Q00?usp=sharing → → When you add a patch, or do other changes to **ns-2.35**  : Use the "configure && make script" = 'install', in the top directory, ns-allinone-2.35/ : `$ export CC=gcc-4.8 CXX=g++-4.8 && ./install`

Comment: About xgraph-12.*/depcomp : Delete the link "depcomp" (if present), and do `$ ln -s /usr/share/automake-*/depcomp`

Comment: Knud - I appreciate the responses. I understand running in the top directory, but I am little confused on how the patches and the `export` commands relate to my issue. Could you provide a little more detail of how those commands relate to my xgraph? I am a little confused on the /decomp as well.

Comment: The mentioned commands are just the ones usually required for ns-2.35. ... About 'depcomp' : The link in xgraph-12.*/ is to a non existing version. Therefore the link must be deleted, and a new one created : To /usr/share/automake-1.16/depcomp